# CXF JAX-RS not working under a specific installation of linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee

Someone was playing with `chmod` or `chown` in order to paste the war files in the TomEE installation directory without deleting the file first, from that moment we had the following problem:

JAX-RS annotated methods with multipart doesn't work anymore, for example, the following method is never reached:

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String test(
        @Multipart(value = "a", required = false) Attachment a,
        @Multipart(value = "b", required = false) Attachment b) {
    System.out.println("THIS IS NEVER PRINTED");
    return "THIS IS NEVER CALLED RETURNED";
}
```

And after 20 seconds (I assume 20 seconds from the OS configuration) we got the following

```
Dec 31, 2015 11:19:43 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Read timed out
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1040)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:610)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:574)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:242)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:227)
        at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Read timed out
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.createAttachments(MessageContextImpl.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.get(MessageContextImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalMessageContext.get(ThreadLocalMessageContext.java:38)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getMultipartBody(AttachmentUtils.java:90)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getAttachments(AttachmentUtils.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider.readFrom(MultipartProvider.java:147)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1032)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:535)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:504)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:566)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.readTillFirstBoundary(AttachmentDeserializer.java:251)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeRootMessage(AttachmentDeserializer.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeAttachments(AttachmentDeserializer.java:92)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:64)
        ... 41 more
```

We thought that it was because of the file size, so we tried again with two 0 byte files and we noted an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

We have done everything from fresh tomee installation to delete everything in the project except that class with that method above.

Any ideas of what could have happened?

Comment: have you checked what's coming in Attachment `a` and `b` ? Or are they being blank?

Comment: With multipart, generally intermediate temp files are used. Maybe it is a permission problem with this, I  don't know.

Comment: Try to create another method (just for test), that accepts application/octet-stream, and have a `File` as a method parameter. Generally with this, there is also a temp file used. See if you have similar problem.

Comment: I created a new project with the same name as the old today and deployed it into the tomee and for my surprise it worked just fine; then I redeployed the old proyect and magically it works.

I changed the permissions for catalina.sh thou to 0777, maybe a temp file with the old permissions was somewhere and was deleted during the night.